# XPages - Repeat Control - Get item Value

Tags: xpages, lotus

I would like to create a custom control which shows 3 columns, 
column 1, value selected from checkbox (this is ok)
column 2, editable box , this is showing but not working 100%
column 3, a button to remove the row (still to be done)

So far:
After selecting the options, click "Create Rows" button and 1 row appears for each selected option.

Problem:
Only last value in editable box, is used, how can I get the value from each box ?
getComponent("inputText1").getValue()  only shows the last value.

Example code is on this URL:

http://snipt.org/AAgd3

Answer (score 3):

You bind the column values to array variables. Exercise 23 has a complete working example: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-Introduction-to-XPages-Exercise-23

You just need to adjust it to the source/destination of your data. Let us know how it goes

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the example and followed the steps, got Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception. Will look at the issue later on

Comment: Step 1 in your development database: switch on standard error page, so it clearly states what's wrong. Btw. the code is from an exercise, something you must DO (and it is number 23, so probably depending on previous steps), not something you copy and paste.

Comment: IBM Link is broken. Archive.org to the rescue:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190423013750/https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-Introduction-to-XPages-Exercise-23

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind them dynamically, you can also do this with expression language. It takes a bit of getting around in order to get the fields editable, but the way I've resolved it is to pass a calculated ID into a custom control, then using that for the binding.

For example: If I'm Working with a list of Unique Part Names, I may pass into my custom control a variable for a Comment. If I pass this in as fieldNameComment to my custom control, I can dynamically bind it to an inputText element through the following code.

I'm using a DominoDocument passed in as the dataSource.

Calling the Custom Control:

```
<xp:repeat var="CurrVal" value="#{DataSource}">
    <xc:DynamicTableRow dataSource="#{EmissionsDocument}">
       <xc:this.fieldNameComment><![CDATA[#{javascript:CurrVal+"Comment"}]]></xc:this.fieldNameComment>
    </xc:DynamicTableRow>
</xp:repeat>
```

Inside the Custom Control:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText5" 
    value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldNameComment]}">
</xp:inputText>
```

As long as (for some reason) none of the string calculations are performed within the expression language syntax, this will yield an editable field. In my testing, if I tried to calculate a value by concatenating any strings, the field would be bound, but not appear as editable under any circumstances. If you want to bind directly to fields, this may be a good approach, but if you want to save your array and parse it through java, then Stephan's solution also works great Hope this helps!

Appended: Added repeat control to show iteration through the data source. Each iteration of the Data Source yeilds a value, CurrVal, to which the string "Comment" is appended. This creates a series of FieldNames based on the Values in the DataSource that are bound to inputs within the custom control called DynamicTableRow

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing Collection Name to CurrRow, but value disappears after it's been saved , so I cannot use CurrRow.getColumnValue("key2") ?

Comment: Sorry, CurrRow.getColumnValue("key2") refers to me using a view to iterate through pre-caculated values. That can be any string you want to bind the data to. I should also add that my code is only working if you're passing data into a custom control, which from your code you don't seem to be. I'll edit my code to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Hmm. It sounds like you don't really have a custom control at all, but you're passing values into a repeat control. I've never had any luck associating value bindings dynamically outside of a repeat control. I'd recommend trying to create the custom control within your repeat control and passing in the calculated values.

Comment: There is no view, item values are from checkboxgroup, see the code I attached. I want to check x boxes from checkboxgroup, the repeat control then creates x rows of 3 columns, 1 first column shows chosen value from check box, 2nd column is an editable field, data to be saved in an external profile document or sessionscope variable, 3rd column would remove the column. currently my code just stores the value from the editable fields in the last row, need the values from the other rows too.

Comment: The custom control is just a checkboxgroup

Comment: Checkboxgroup is a default control, though. I'll append my code above with a little more clarity.

Comment: Michael Saiz has the solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392858/getting-values-from-repeat-control/16393978#16393978  it does what I wanted, just need to figure out how to add an "Remove" button