# Xpages - Repeat Control field not editable

Tags: controls, xpages, repeat

I used the example from this question as a starting point [Getting values from repeat control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392858/getting-values-from-repeat-control/16393978#16393978)

the field in example from link above is : 
`<xp:inputText id="inputText1" loaded="true">
 <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:var fieldName = "Help_" + varcollection;
    return '#{viewScope.' + fieldName + '}';}]]></xp:this.value>
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1"></xp:eventHandler></xp:inputText>`

The code for the field I have now is a modified version from above :

`<xp:inputText id="inputText1" loaded="true">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var fieldName = "Tmp_" + @ReplaceSubstring(varcollection," ","");
 return '#{viewScope.' + @ReplaceSubstring(fieldName," ","") + '}';}]]></xp:this.value>
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"                                           refreshId="panel1" /></xp:inputText>`

but for some reason it's not an editable field, any idea why ?

Also, although idea above is good, if I have 4 editable fields in 1 row, I would have to create 4 viewScope variables per row ? Is there another way to store the field values ?

running on Domino 8.5.3

Comment: I added a button with onclick  :
var tmp1 = "";
var tmp2 = -1;
if (sessionScope.get("s1d") != null)
{
tmp1 = sessionScope.get("s1").indexOf(varcollection);
if (tmp1 != -1)
{
tmp2 = sessionScope.get("s1").splice(tmp1,1);
sessionScope.put("s1",tmp2); 
}}`

and as Partial Update the panel with button but doesn't seem to update.
it's working fine if I want to remove 1 item but if I want to remove 2 items it's not working as the buttons seem to store the initial value.
ie, values 1,2,3,4
when I click on button to remove on row 3, I get 1,2,4 ok
when I click on button on row 4 I get 1,2,3 again ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace #{javascript: with ${javascript.
Or change the Code in the value to onLoad (wich is the same as the change between # and $), this should make you fields editable again.

Instead of using 4 or more scope variables per row and you dont know how many you need in the end you could use a Bean that `implements com.ibm.xsp.model.DataObject`. 
See [Link](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/18.03.2011104725KLEDH8.htm).The benefit from implementing the DataObject interface is that you can access your beanData direct via [EL](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/BP212_LS11.pdf/%24file/BP212_LS11.pdf).