# Xpages - CompositeData - Repeat Control

Tags: controls, xpages, repeat

I have a repeat control, repeatControls = false, rendered = true, using both indexVar and var. Value is an array from a sessionScope variable, so if 4 values, 4 items are shown.

Printing Computed Fields isn't an issue
I added an Edit Box inside repeat and set it to bind data using compositeData.editField1
no Partial refreshes

Then there is a button which has to set the data of all rows of editable fields to a sessionScope variable,

if I just do 
sessionScope.put("editField1", compositeData.editField1), I just get the value of the last row. how to add the values of the other rows of edtitable fields ? There are no bindings to Notes views or documents as they aren't needed. Thanks

Comment: Check out my Answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392858/getting-values-from-repeat-control/16393978#16393978

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example with compositeData and repeatControls="false", I need to set it to false because panel that contains repeat control is going to be refreshed

Comment: Doing this with repeatControls="false" is a bit tricky because you cant access the var propertie anymore. I would try to avoid setting it to false, whats the problem with the refresh? Maby post some code?

Comment: It's ok for all the fields except if you put a button in the repeat control. I added a "remove row" button which is working and then refreshes panel, a modified function for button should appear which is not the case, guess I have to write a different script for remove function

Answer (score 0):

If you have input fields, you need to bind them. Binding them to a scope is perfectly fine. In the same question Michael was pointing to is the link to a sample with add/remove row logic (just substract the part where it goes back to the field).

[Excercise 23](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-Introduction-to-XPages-Exercise-23) has all you need.